# linq to sql insert when record is already present

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an object that has a property called ObjectID that maps to the primary key of a table in the DB.

What happens if you do a linq-to-sql insert and attempt to do an insert with an object with an ObjectID already present in the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get a message like this `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_some_key'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'someTable'. The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after test:
if the entity you trying to insert new to the datacontext even if the primarykey value already exists it will insert a new entity `with new ID`

if the entity you trying to insert is pulled from the same datacontext then it will throws this exception `Cannot add an entity that already exists.`

anyway you can try it by yourself to insure this.